# Avoid recursivity with generic method to set class properties c#

Tags: c#, properties, setter

I follow to explain my problem in a much bigger class with an smaller easy to follow exact example.
I got quite a big class, with a lot of properties of different types, getting and setting their respective class variable.

```
public class Foo() {
    int property1 { get => _property1 ; set => _property1 = value;}
    string property2 { get => _property2 ; set => _property2 = value;}
    Vector3 property3 { get => _property3 ; set => _property3 = value;}
    bool property4 { get => _property3 ; set => _property4 = value;}
}
```

I put 4 properties in the example, but in the real example there are a lot.
I need to apply a logic in the set of all the properties, depending on property4 boolean, so instead of writting the same code in all the setters of my properties, I tried to make a generic method to be called in all of them.

So, I made a an enum:

```
public enum properties {
    property1,
    property2,
    property3,
    property4
}
```

So that I can set my properties with a method that involves reflection, taking the property type as an argument:

```
public void setLogic<T>(properties property, T value) {
    //irrelevant code
}
```

So my setters turn to be:

```
public class Foo() {
    int property1 { get => _property1 ; set { setLogic(properties.property1 , value) };}
    string property2 { get => _property2 ; set { setLogic(properties.property2 , value) };}
    Vector3 property3 { get => _property3 ; set { setLogic(properties.property3 , value) };}
    bool property4 { get => _property4 ; set{ _property4 = value) };}
}
```

My problem comes when in my setLogic() the property setter is called recursively producing a stack overflow. So I solved the topic with a boolean controlled from setLogic() that controlls where the setter is being called from.
So now my properties turn to be:

```
public class Foo() {
    int property1 { 
        get => _property1; 
        set { 
            if (!_calledFromSetLogic)
                setLogic(properties.property1 , value);
            else {
                _property1 = value;
                _calledFromSetLogic = false;
            }
        }
    }
    string property2 { 
        get => _property2; 
        set { 
            if (!_calledFromSetLogic)
                setLogic(properties.property2 , value);
            else {
                _property2 = value;
                _calledFromSetLogic = false;
            }
        }
    }
    Vector3 property3 { 
        get => _property3; 
        set { 
            if (!_calledFromSetLogic)
                setLogic(properties.property3 , value);
            else {
                _property3 = value;
                _calledFromSetLogic = false;
            }
        }
    }
    bool property4 { get => property4; set{ _property4 = value) };}
}
```

The code works fine, but the setter bool control to avoid recursivity throws away all the possible cleannes brought by the SetLogic() generic method. On the other hand I cannot set the class variables in the setLogic method because I access the properties with reflection, so to set the new value in the logic I cannot avoid the recursive set without the boolean (property.SetValue() from the reflection class sets the new value calling the set once again, so infinite loop).

If I dont do this, I have to paste the setLogic() method, instead of been generic, copy pasted for each of the properties in the set, which is not very clean code neither.

Is there not a clean solution for this, where the setter can be passed as an argument, or a generic method that avoids infinite recursive set?

I was thinking of something like

```
private setLogic<T>(Action<> setterMethod, T value) {
    //so that the property involved might be already in the setter?
}
```

or other kind of setLogic with the generic class properties that avoids the infinite loop, of whom a cannot think of.

Hope I made myself understood.

Comment: Reflection is a very slow way to set a property value, as compared to setting it directly - and you haven't made clear for what purpose you are setting the properties in this way; as-is, the first code snippet is most definitely the cleanest, and you're "duplicating" code anyways by calling setLogic in all of the setters, just duplicating it a different way. In any case, you should include the setLogic function because as it stands this question lacks a lot of clarity and lacks a key component to determining why this is causing recursion.

Comment: The question is long. I tried to make clear what make the recursion here: (property.SetValue() from the reflection class sets the new value calling the set once again, so infinite loop). If there is any doubt on that or I can give any further explanation I will be glado to.

Comment: Regarding reflection being slow, the concren of this question is not eficiency, is to write clean/compact code. With the scenario I explained, I have to check setter with boolean so setters get long if there are lots of them. With no generic method, I have to write the exact same set logic code in all the setters. In both cases code gets long and repeated with exact same patterns so the question is if there could be any other more compact way for the code of this scenario

Comment: My recommendation would be to back the property with a private field, and set that field in your setLogic function instead of calling the property setter. Alternately, check if the new value is the same as the existing value prior to calling the setter. Alternately, and I recommend this mainly because the only supplied reason for writing the code this way is cleanness, go back to using the first snippet - it is the cleanest of all of the available options in terms of standardization.

Comment: +1 for check if the new value is the same in the setter. Regarding "go back to using the first snippet" I explain why the required logic in the setter and not being able to access the private variables because I access the properties with reflection, makes not possible to use the first simple snippet, that would be the desirable thing

Comment: I'm sorry, I re-read the question now and can see why that was not a useful suggestion - post-work brain had me misinterpreting. I am glad Jeff E was better able to comprehend the reasoning behind the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you able to just use a `ref` parameter to set the field directly?:

```cs
int property1
{
    get => _property1;
    set => setLogic(ref _property1, value);
}

private void setLogic<T>(ref T field, T value)
{
    field = value;
}
```

I commonly use this pattern when implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
private int _someProperty;
public int SomeProperty
{
    get => _someProperty;
    set => SetProperty(ref _someProperty, value);
}

private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] propertyName = "")
{
    if (!field.Equals(value))
    {
        field = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: fck i was exactly writing this. I think this is the good way. As MVVM light setter.

Comment: This answer solves exactly the problem I exposed. Thanks a lot for the nailed anwer!! However, what I set is not a private variable, I get and set another property from a nested class so y get a compilation error when I try to pass that by reference: "a property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter". From here on I will try to figure out the best solution. Anyhow I am glad to be aware of this pattern for cleaner code :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute and a `Dictionary<string, object>` to store the properties in. This won't incur the same performance penalties reflection would.

For example...

```cs
class Foo : PropertyChangeNotifier
{
    public int property1 { get { return Get<int>(); } set { Set(value); } }
    public string property2 { get { return Get<string>(); } set { Set(value); } }
    public Vector3 property3 { get { return Get<Vector3>(); } set { Set(value); } }
    public bool property4 { get { return Get<bool>(); } set { Set(value); } }

    protected override void OnSet<T>(string property, T value)
    {
        // do something meaningful.
    }
}
```

...and the base class...

```cs
abstract class PropertyChangeNotifier
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        return (T)properties[property];
    }

    protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        OnSet(property, value);
        properties[property] = value;
    }

    protected abstract void OnSet<T>(string property, T value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 for the proposal and for the // do something meaningful